# How to add all values in a column in MS Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am having a worksheet where I am having the values as

```
--------------------
col1 | col2
--------------------
1    | 2 min 30 secs  
2    | 1 min 24 secs  
3    | 0 min 10 secs  
4    | 1 min  3 secs
```

Now I would like to sum up all the values in `col2`. Sum will be: `4 min 67 secs`.

Comment: is that text in col2 or only a formatted time?

Comment: you can sum up values like time but not text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here a working example, simply format your timecells to show "m \m\i\n s \s\e\c\s"
and sum them up..:

http://sourcemonk.com/sum_of_formatted_time.xlsx